# Network printer - Idle - Waiting for printer to finish

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, canon

I've installed Canon driver for Ubuntu 16.04, from [this](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/support-laser-printers-imageclass/imageclass-lbp6300dn?tab=drivers#Z7_MQH8HIC0L88RB0AMD0F1Q42K25) url.
When I try to print test page, is fails saying "Idle - Waiting for printer to finish." but there is nothing in printing queue. Other people are able to normally print from Windows machines.

[image]

How can I make it work?